# CSS4 :matches() for parent and not children element

Tags: css, css-selectors

The new selector `:matches()` from CSS4 allow us to write

```
:matches(section, article, aside) h1 {
    color: red;
}

/* instead of */

section h1, article h1, aside h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

**but**, is there any way to write something shorter than this

```
section h1, section p, section span {
    color: red;
}

/* with something like */

section:matches(h1, p, span) {
    color: red;
}
```

*where `h1`, `p` and `span` can not be considered as `*`*

Comment: you are probably looking for this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Do note that `:matches` https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Amatches browser support is limited the same goes for `:has` https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am not looking to apply style on parent, just a way to write `section h1, section p, section span` simpler

Comment: @SuperDJ it's about CSS4 so it's still under construction and I am sure the OP is aware about

Comment: @SuperDJ yop, thank you to remind but I'm aware of support

Comment: `section h1` means that h1 is a (not necessarily direct) childnode of section. (it was a direct child if you had it `section>h1`). section:matches(h1) would require "section" to be "h1" which is impossible as both are a tag and not a .class or #id. you're looking for it's children. thus `section *:matches(...)` comes closer to your example. (note the wildcard asterisk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
section h1, section p, section span {
    color: red;
}
```

would actually be:

```
section :matches(h1, p, span) { /* note the space */
    color: red;
}
```

This works in Chrome at present **if "Experimental Web Platform features" flag is enabled.**

```css
section :matches(h1, p, span) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Red H1</h1>
  <p>Red Paragraph</p>
  <span>Red Span</span>
  <h2>Not red H2</h2>
</section>
```

[**Support**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo) though is poor at present

Result Image (for those without the flag)

[image]

Comment: Uh! I do not understand you here... I have the latest version of Chrome (Version 68.0.3440.106) on Windows, and I see everything black here, not red.

Comment: Works for me in Version 69.0.3497.32 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: But I have Experimental Features enabled

Comment: yes, as we can see, you are in "beta" version, caniuse.com declare it at : "Not supported by default, but can be enabled".

Comment: No...there's a flag in Chrome settings that you can set to enable this in stable versions of Chrome. Regardless, the syntax is correct - https://www.howtogeek.com/179070/how-to-get-access-to-experimental-features-on-your-chromebook-or-just-in-chrome/ I've added an image of the result.